# Java Swings JTextField not appearing properly, it is appearing like a slit

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, gridbaglayout

I have create a `JLabel`, which display a background image, and then I am adding three buttons and a `JTextField`, and the layout of `JLable` is `GridBagLayout`, but the main problem is the size of the `JTextField`. What is my mistake ? I have tried `preferredSize` as well as `setBounds`. I am new to `GridBagLayout`.

```
    p = new JPanel();
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/manpreet/Desktop/G.L.E.W/3.jpg");
    l = new JLabel(img);

        practice = new JButton("Practice (No Time Limit)");
        Challenge = new JButton("Challenge (60 Seconds)");

        l.setLayout(g);
        practice.setFont(new Font("Garamond", Font.BOLD, 20));
        practice.setForeground(Color.yellow);
        practice.setBackground(Color.black);

Challenge.setBackground(Color.black);
    Challenge.setFont(new Font("Garamond", Font.BOLD, 20));
        Challenge.setForeground(Color.yellow);


        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        l.add(practice,gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth=1;
    Insets insets1 = new Insets(2,2,2,2);
        gbc.insets = insets1;

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        l.add(Challenge,gbc);
        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;

        t = new JTextField("TextField");
        //t.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,20));      
        //t.setBounds(5,5,20,20);

        start = new JButton("start");
        t.setVisible(true);
        start.setVisible(true);
        l.add(t,gbc);
        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        l.add(start,gbc);           
        p.add(l);
        f.add(p);       
        f.pack();
        practice.addActionListener(this);
        Challenge.addActionListener(this);
```

Comment: remove f.pack(). that should help you in right direction

Comment: @Sanjeev No. Do NOT remove the pack(). The pack() is required to display components at their preferred size. The problem is that the text field is NOT displayed at its preferred size.

Comment: So you are trying to add the buttons and textField into the label with the picture? And you see the buttons and the image, but the textField shows up as a line? Just need some clarifying what you are seeing.

Comment: thanks everyone, but actually I have found my mistake, after using gridwidth=1 the code is working fine, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you want people to take the time to look at your code then you should:

1. use meaningful variable names. "l" "t" mean nothing and it is hard to follow the code to understand what those variables represent.
2. follow Java naming conventions. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. It looks like all your variable names (except "Challenge") are correct. Be consistent!!!

> JTextField not appearing properly, it is appearing like a vertical line

This happens when there is not enough space in the frame to display the component at its preferred size. GridBagLayout will then display the component at its minimum size which is why you get a really small text field.

The basic code looks reasonable since you do a pack(). However, maybe somewhere else you override the pack() with a setSize(...) or something.

If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: From now I will follow Conventions for naming the variables. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) You can specify column count for `JTextField` like : `t = new JTextField("TextField",20);`

2) With help of `GridBagConstraints` parametrs: `weightx` and `fill`.

3) Avoid using:

```
 setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,20));      
 setBounds(5,5,20,20);
```

Read more about [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

Example:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class TestFrame extends JFrame{

    public TestFrame(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        init();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JTextField f1 = new JTextField("text",10);
        JTextField f2 = new JTextField("text");

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        add(f1,c);
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1;
        add(f2,c);
    }


    public static void main(String... strings) {
        new TestFrame();
    }
}
```

[image]